# CMake: Including static libraries and resolving transitive dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a project in which I need to use NAG libraries (libnagc_nag.a) and build the project using CMake. On my system NAG is installed at `/usr/lib/NAG26`. The directory for the library is `/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib`.

There are also header files which my project will use (`nag.h, nag_stdlib.h, nagf08.h, nagx04.h`). Following is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(AnyProject VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

configure_file(AnyProject.h.in AnyProject.h)

find_library(LIB_TO_INCLUDE nagc_nag "/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib")

find_path(LIB_INCLUDES nag.h "/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/include")
find_path(LIB_INCLUDES nag_stdlib.h "/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/include")
find_path(LIB_INCLUDES nagf08.h "/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/include")
find_path(LIB_INCLUDES nagx04.h "/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/include")

add_executable(AnyProject ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(AnyProject PUBLIC ${LIB_INCLUDES})
target_include_directories(AnyProject PUBLIC
                           ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
                           )

target_link_libraries(AnyProject ${LIB_TO_INCLUDE})
```

I have couple of questions

1. The above CMakeLists.txt throws an error at the time of build :

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libifcoremt.so.5, needed by /usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libsvml.so, needed by /usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libimf.so, needed by /usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libirc.so, needed by /usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so: undefined reference to `__gtq'
/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so: undefined reference to `for_f90_index'
/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so: undefined reference to `for_close'
/usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d/lib/libnagc_nag.so: undefined reference to `__intel_sse4_strspn'
.
.
.
```

I understand that CMake is not able to figure out the transitive dependency. The files `libsvml.so, libimf.so, libirc.so, libifcoremt.so.5` are located in the same directory as `libnagc_nag.a and libnagc_nag.so` which was added to target_include_directories. How to resolve this? I guess I should not be having to explicitly include the transitive dependencies here, or do I ?

2. Is there a way to not specify the exact path of `*.a` libraries I wish to link and have CMake find it for me ? For my system I know where NAG is installed, but I won't know where it is installed for some other system. How to make the above CMakeLists.txt more portable ?
3. Is there a way to include all (necessary) header files from a directory instead of including them one by one (which will be tedious if there were too many of them) ?.

I am using CMake for the first time so my questions might not be well formed. Any general advice with respect to above issues will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which was added to target_include_directories. How to resolve this ?

`target_include_directories` adds `#include` directories. `target_link_directories` adds library search paths. Add the path to library search paths.

> Is there a way to not specify the exact path of *.a libraries I wish to link and have CMake find it for me ?

No, CMake has to know the paths to libraries.

You can add the directory to `target_link_directories` and have **compiler** search for your libraries in library search paths when linking.

> How to make the above CMakeLists.txt more portable ?

To make your CMake more portable, lower the required minimum version, there are still machines even with CMake 2.8. CMake checks portability by itself with the specified version. Personally, I stick  to CMake `3.11`, but for no reason.

> Is there a way to include all (necessary) header files from a directory instead of including them one by one (which will be tedious if there were too many of them) ?

CMake does not include C header files.

In C programming language, create a header that `#include`s all the files and then include that header in your C source files.

> Any general advice

Calling multiple `find_path` with the same variable is pointless - new calls are omitted, because the CMake cache variable already exists.

Well, re-read about CMake and some CMake introduction and an introduction to C compilation stages - about compiling and linking. You maybe want to research CMake `IMPORTED` libraries and most probably `ExternalProject_Add` utility.

There's no point in searching for header files or library files if you know they are there. Search for stuff if you are not sure if it is there, to be portable between environments that do not have that "stuff". Like some environments do not have `unistd.h` - so you can check that in CMake and then differently compile code to handle such case - achieving portability.

> with respect to above issues will be appreciated.

I in this case I would just go with one `INTERFACE` library so it looks nice:

```
add_library(nag INTERFACE)
set(nag_path /usr/lib/NAG26/cll6i261d)
target_include_directories(nag INTERFACE "${nag_path}"/include)
target_link_directories(nag INTERFACE "${nag_path}"/lib)
target_link_libraries(nag INTERFACE ifcoremt svml imf irc)

target_link_libraries(AnyProject PRIVATE nag)
```

But maybe creating an `IMPORTED` library for each `ifcoremt svml imf irc` would be a nicer approach.